# Hide android application package from PackageManager

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

It is well known that PackageManager's methods

```
getInstalledApplications(int flags) 
getInstalledPackages(int flags)
```

returns a list of installed applications.So my question is,it is possible to hide your application from package manager and it wouldn't be in the list returned by the above methods ?

Comment: No.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: For example : Another "rival" application detects my application installed on the device and claims to uninstall my app,otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: What makes you think any arbitrary package can uninstall another arbitrary package?

Comment: Nothing! I mean the "rival" app detect my app and suggest user that he should delete my app

Comment: @user4083522 facing same scenario where rival/competitor refusing service to user if they have installed our service also where user wants to use both and as user can't afford to lose using rival service due to given benefits he uninstalls our service. Did you found any solution?

Comment: @DougStevenson There are many situations where people don't want to share their privacy with apps. An installed app list is one of the most important privacy to me. For example, my country does not allow people to use google, youtube and twitter. By installing any of my country origin apps, I might go to jail if I have youtube installed.